# I am trying to install pandas (python3.9) in mac os and facing error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, macos

**I am trying to install pandas in my Mac OS and facing an error. I have recently installed python3.9. I am new to python.
some libraries like NumPy and scipy are installed using homebrew
trying installing with homebrew showing me another error

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "pandas".
**

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/y9/02mz9m7s2970mz8k77cgbng80000gn/T/pip-build-env-p4vzzze2/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (229 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.21
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting numpy
    Using cached numpy-1.19.5.zip (7.3 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/y9/02mz9m7s2970mz8k77cgbng80000gn/T/tmp_nyvr3sn
           cwd: /private/var/folders/y9/02mz9m7s2970mz8k77cgbng80000gn/T/pip-install-nfwyqhvs/numpy_a96abd5ed3de4c71ba29057fb2c27e1f
      Complete output (209 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.
      setup.py:480: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
      Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
      Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
      Cythonizing sources
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      blis_info:
        libraries blis not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries tatlas not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        libraries satlas not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_blas_info:
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      accelerate_info:
        libraries accelerate not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      Library accelerate was not found. Ignoring
        libraries veclib not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      Library veclib was not found. Ignoring
        FOUND:
          extra_compile_args = ['-faltivec', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
          extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
          define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
  
        FOUND:
          extra_compile_args = ['-faltivec', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
          extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
          define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
  
      non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_lapack_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_clapack_info:
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      flame_info:
        libraries flame not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
[![enter image description here][1]][1]File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 756, in encode
          raise TypeError("str expected, not %s" % type(value).__name__)
      TypeError: str expected, not int
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/y9/02mz9m7s2970mz8k77cgbng80000gn/T/tmp_nyvr3sn Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/y9/02mz9m7s2970mz8k77cgbng80000gn/T/pip-build-env-p4vzzze2/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```